# Calling function from another swift file from SwiftUI button doesn’t listen to return from function

Tags: ios, swift, binding, swiftui, closures

So migrating project from storyboard to swiftUI & figuring out swiftUI
We want business logic out of the swiftUI code

We have our login code technically working it works makes restful call but the flow is wrong in the button action

On login button action it calls authController().login(email,password)

In the login function  I have it return bool

But in the button action it just keeps running to the next function without waiting for the return it needs

Have tried attaching a let to auth.login & working that way
If statements nothing it just runs all functions at once

Have not tired defer yet

Any suggestions or links to what I am missing

editing due to original was typed on my phone

this is the swiftUI

```
Button(action: {
LoginViewController().requestLogin(loginEmail: loginEmail,loginPassword: loginPassword)
self.goHome = true
 }
```

that self.goHome moves the user to the next scene it don't matter what requestLogin is doing or what logic is in there it just proceeds

the requestLogin is using alamoFireManager for the API calls

```swift
// MARK: - Log In
    func requestLogin(loginEmail: String, loginPassword: String){
        //disable controls
        enableControls(isEnabled: false)
        
        //create request header and parameters
        let loginParameters: [String: Any] = ["email": loginEmail, "password": loginPassword]
        let header = ["Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"]
        //setup configuration object
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(timeout)
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TimeInterval(timeout)
        //setup alamofire session manager
        alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
        //send request
        alamoFireManager?.request(serverAddress + loginApi, method: .post, parameters: loginParameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
            .responseJSON {response in
                //enable controls
                self.enableControls(isEnabled: true)
                //SignUp response process
                if let resultJson = processJsonData(responseData: response.data) {
                    isChecking = self.processLoginResponse(result: resultJson)
                } else {
                    //Sign up failed
                    showAlert(parent: self, title: "Login Failed", message: "Login failed, please check the network connection and try it again.")
                }


            }
    }
```

Comment: Include some code so we can see what's happening.

Comment: You definitely need to [edit] your question to show relevant code, but given that you mention RESTful calls, I assume your login needs to perform a network operation to authenticate the user.  If this is the case, it isn't possible for your login function to return a bool; The network operation will complete asynchronously.  Your login function needs a completion handler.  In that completion handler you can update the state in your model object.  SwiftUI will use that change in state to update the view that is shown

Comment: hey @Paulw11 i believe your right, on the completion handler not my strongest area.so some nightly reading ahead of me.

i also added code for helping towards

Comment: You don't want to set `self.goHome` to `true` straight away. You need to set this in the completion handler. You will probably want to use an `ObservableObject` with an `@Published` property as your model. After the login succeeds you will set the property in your model and the view will react to that.

Comment: cheers @Paulw11 I think I may go back to Laravel!